# Error when writing header column in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write the column names to the first row of an excel sheet using xlsxwriter module.

The below code prints out the column names of my SQL:

```
title = [i[0] for i in dwh_cursor.description]
print(title)
```

To write this to the excel sheet I am trying the below:

```
current_row = 0
for data in title:
    worksheet1.write(current_row, data)
```

Get the below error:

```
TypeError: write() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Based on the docs for [the XlsxWriter Worksheet](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html) this should "just work." Can you show how you set up `worksheet1`?

Comment: @s3cur3: This is only True if you do `write('A1', *args)`, but using `row/col` you have to do `write(row, col, *args)`.

Comment: Ah, right you are @stovfl!